# Building rudimentary data binding with jQuery but variables are not scoping properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, scope

I am attempting to replicate some basic data binding with a view template, from a controller. I am building it using straight JS and jQuery. There is a variable in my controller function I want to change when the user inputs into a field. The events are firing properly but the variable remains unchanged. Whats the best way to scope the variables so this will work:

```
function myController() {
    var password = '1234';

    //handle data binding 
bindTo = function(elem, prop) {

    console.log('original stored prop = ' + prop); //this logs out 1234 
            //BUT only the first time
            //on every subsequent keypress it logs out the value that the user types
            //which has no effect on the var password in the controller                

    var elem = $(elem);
    var value = elem.val();

     // Save current value of element
    elem.data('oldVal', value);

    // Look for changes in the value
    elem.bind("propertychange keyup input paste", function(event){
        console.log('inside bind fn prop = ' + prop)
    var val = elem.val();
    // If value has changed...
    if (elem.data('oldVal') != val) {
        // Updated stored value
        elem.data('oldVal', val);
        prop = val; //where is prop being set?
        console.log(prop); //this logs my value properly
     }
   });

};

//set bindings
bindTo($('input.loginPassword')[0], password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function myController(elem, prop) {
var password = '1234';


bindTo = function(elem, prop) {

console.log('original stored prop = ' + prop); //this logs out 1234 
        //BUT only the first time
        //on every subsequent keypress it logs out the value that the user types
        //which has no effect on the var password in the controller                

var elem = $(elem);
var value = elem.val();

 // Save current value of element
elem.data('oldVal', value);

// Look for changes in the value
elem.bind("propertychange keyup input paste", function(event){
    console.log('inside bind fn prop = ' + prop)
var val = elem.val();
// If value has changed...
if (elem.data('oldVal') != val) {
    // Updated stored value
    elem.data('oldVal', val);
    prop = val; //where is prop being set?
    console.log(prop); //this logs my value properly
 }
 });

     }(elem, prop);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to be able to possibly bind many variables together. As well it looks like the (elem, prop) at the end makes it self executing? Is that a necessary part of the scoping? I guess my main question is about the 'prop' param that I pass in to bindTo(). How can I get it to actually relate to the scope of myController. At one point it seems to and then later it doesn't. Perhaps its because I am inadvertently creating a 'prop' var in the local scope of the function, so it never gets back to the original var that prop represented in the main myController function.

Comment: the (elem,prop) in the last line does the scoping, which is also included in the FrontController Function. @ScottWright

Comment: Thanks for the scoping technique. I still feel like I have a way to go before I can to where I want to be with this code. It feels like there should be another way. The structure of the app and the way I want to  use the controller doesn't allow for this implementation.